# Bash Script Not allowing special symbols in zipping a file

Tags: bash, macos, zip, symlink, symlink-traversal

I am actually creating a zip file based on a pdf file that I have downloaded through java code, so the problem statement is like this.

I have a pdf file with special symbols =  `(wallbay)+1-50 m+ ipad+i pho ne%watch.pdf`

Now I want this file to be created as a zip file which should have a name = `(wallbay\)+1-50m+ipad+iphone%watch.pdf.zip`

I tried below commands :

```
cd /Users/rkr5/Downloads/admin && zip --symlinks -r \(wallbay\)+1-50m+ipad+iphone%watch.pdf.zip   \(wallbay)+1-50 m+ ipad+i pho ne%watch.pdf
                        
cd /Users/rkr5/Downloads/admin && zip --symlinks -r "\(wallbay)+1-50 m+ ipad+i pho ne%watch.pdf.zip"   "\(wallbay)+1-50 m+ ipad+i pho ne%watch.pdf"
                        
cd /Users/rkr5/Downloads/admin && zip --symlinks -r \(wallbay)+1-50 m+ ipad+i pho ne%watch.pdf.zip   "\(wallbay)+1-50 m+ ipad+i pho ne%watch.pdf"
```

None of them are working and throwing error like ``` "parse error near ``)'" ```

The only command that works is

```
cd /Users/rkr5/Downloads/admin && zip --symlinks -r \(wallbay\)+1-50m+ipad+iphone%watch.pdf.zip    \(wallbay\)+1-50m+ipad+iphone%watch.pdf
```

But above commands work only when there is no whitespaces in pdf filename.

Currently my folder structure is

```
/Users/rkr5/Downloads/admin/(wallbay)+1-50m+ipad+iphone%watch.pdf.zip
/Users/rkr5/Downloads/admin/(wallbay)+1-50 m+ ipad+i pho ne%watch.pdf
```

I am using MacOs currently..

Comment: The first edit is free, have a look so you know for future questions.  The easiest way to tackle this is to write a script that will cleanup your filenames (removing or replacing special chars and spaces).  Otherwise everything you do will be hindered by these filenames.  Your question has 2 aspects.  Renaming the file, and processing special characters.  One generic method you could use is with `find .... -print0`, as described here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the names of the files contain characters that are interpreted by the shell (like `(` and `)`) or white space, you need to either escape or quote them.

I'd recommend quoting: it's easier and requires that you just surround the ***unmodified*** filename with double quotes (`"`) as follows:

```
cd /Users/rkr5/Downloads/admin && zip --symlinks -r "(wallbay)+1-50 m+ ipad+i pho ne%watch.pdf.zip" "(wallbay)+1-50 m+ ipad+i pho ne%watch.pdf"
```

If you prefer, you can use a shell variable to avoid repeting the filename twice:

```
filename="(wallbay)+1-50 m+ ipad+i pho ne%watch.pdf"
cd /Users/rkr5/Downloads/admin && zip --symlinks -r "$filename.zip" "$filename"
```

(Since you are compressing only one file, the option `-r` is not necessary.)

**Why don't your commands work?**

This command:

```
cd /Users/rkr5/Downloads/admin && zip --symlinks -r \(wallbay\)+1-50m+ipad+iphone%watch.pdf.zip   \(wallbay)+1-50 m+ ipad+i pho ne%watch.pdf
```

doesn't work because white space and the second parenthesis in the PDF filename are not escaped.

This command:

```
cd /Users/rkr5/Downloads/admin && zip --symlinks -r "\(wallbay)+1-50 m+ ipad+i pho ne%watch.pdf.zip"   "\(wallbay)+1-50 m+ ipad+i pho ne%watch.pdf"
```

doesn't work because it is **both** quoted **and** (partially) escaped.

This command:

```
cd /Users/rkr5/Downloads/admin && zip --symlinks -r \(wallbay)+1-50 m+ ipad+i pho ne%watch.pdf.zip   "\(wallbay)+1-50 m+ ipad+i pho ne%watch.pdf"
```

doesn't work because the it is **both** quoted **and** (partially) escaped, and a double quote is missing at the end of the name of the zip archive.

Comment: @RajeshKumar I'm glad I could help, if you think my answer solves your issue, please consider marking it as accepted, it will help others with a similar issue. Thanks!